# SELECT in Table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a table like that :

```
    ID           MANAGER_ID        NAME
    1              2               Ahmed
    2              3               Mostafa
    3              NULL            Mohamed
    4              1               Abbas
    5              3               Abdallah
```

If I wanted a sql statement to get the name of the managers in this company! 
how it will be?

Comment: I think someone solved it here .. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a little trickier than it seems at first glance:

```
select Name
from t
where id in (select manager_id from t)
```

The query seems to require some sort of self-join, because the information about who is a manager is in the `manager_id` column.  This does the self-join using `in` in the `where` clause

Comment: Yes that what I needed, "in" .. Thanks a lot, I think that will work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
SELECT NAME from table_name
```

I just realized that you want it only where the Manager is NULL,

```
SELECT NAME from table_name WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL
```

As I have been pointed out this will exude manager 3 because he is a manager as he manages other users. See @Gordon's answer.

Comment: This will not work.  user 3 is a manager, because he is listed as a manager of other users, but you have just excluded him.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select Name 
from TABLENAME 
WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This will deselect Mohamed, who is a manager (His id appears in the manager_id column of other staff, so he is a manager), so this will not work.

Comment: You misunderstand the meaning of the manager_id column.  It's not the person's manager id.  It is who is the manager of that person.  Example - Ahmed's manager_id is 2, meaning that Mostafa is Ahmed's manager.

Although this isn't clear in the OP's question, it seems like the most likely purpose of a manager_id on a record for a person.  I've seen tutorial examples that have tables like this.

Comment: I don't think so, it will select Mostafa, Mohamed and Ahmed, whereas yours will select Ahmed, Mostafa, Abbas and Abdalla

Comment: Sorry, I'm not normally this pedantic, but I found the trickiness of the question interesting enough to do the leg work and create this - http://i.imgur.com/5C0CK2f.jpg

Comment: thanks so much, i just realized there are two same manager ids